# Intellij idea не видит библиотеку для RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rest

Пытаюсь создать RESTful приложениее, но Intellij idea не видит библиотеку, смена версии JAVA EE не помогает. Как можно решить эту проблему? Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы сначала меняеете версию JEE или нажимаете на WS? Попробуйте закрыть это окно и создать проект заного, только изначально поменяйте версию JEE

Comment: @Anton помогло, спасибо большое